# Find AzureAD IDP Enterprise Apps with Users/Groups AND Owners

Tags: azure-powershell, idp

Trying to export all Azure AD IDP Enterprise applications with their associated Users and Groups and Owners.  I'm able to grab the Users and Groups but not the owners with this:

```
foreach($servicePrincipal in $ServicePrincipalList){  
Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $ServicePrincipal.objectId | Select-Object ResourceDisplayName, ResourceId, PrincipalDisplayName, PrincipalType | Export-Csv -Path "C:\\PSReports\\AzureAD_IDP_Apps - $date.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append  
}
```

which produces this:
AzureAD_IDP_Apps Export Screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/U002O.png)

Even if the application does not have any owners assigned, I'd like the report to show it.

Tried finding the PrincipalType for the "Owners" value but was unable to find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it. When adding -join if there are multiple owners and it adds it as a single string separated by a semi-colon:

```
Connect-AzureAD
$date = Get-Date -Format “yyyyMMddHHmmss”
$ServicePrincipalList = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true
*foreach($servicePrincipal in $ServicePrincipalList){ *
$owners = Get-AzureADServicePrincipalOwner -ObjectId $servicePrincipal.ObjectId | Select-Object DisplayName, UserPrincipalName*
$appRoles = Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId 
$servicePrincipal.ObjectId | Select-Object ResourceDisplayName, ResourceId, PrincipalDisplayName, PrincipalType*
$report = $appRoles | Select-Object ResourceDisplayName, ResourceId, PrincipalDisplayName, PrincipalType*
$report | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name “OwnerDisplayName” -Value ($owners.DisplayName -join ‘;’)*
$report | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name “OwnerUserPrincipalName” -Value ($owners.UserPrincipalName -join ‘;’)*
$report | Export-Csv -Path “C:\PSReports\AzureAD_IDP_Apps-$date.csv” -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force*
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> Tried finding the PrincipalType for the "Owners" value but was unable to find it

You can use the below code to get the owner of the service principal and you can export all Azure AD IDP Enterprise applications with their associated Users and Groups and Owners.

**Command:**

```
 $date = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmmss"
$ServicePrincipalList = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true

foreach($servicePrincipal in $ServicePrincipalList){  
    $owners = Get-AzureADServicePrincipalOwner -ObjectId $servicePrincipal.ObjectId | Select-Object DisplayName, UserPrincipalName
    $appRoles = Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $servicePrincipal.ObjectId | Select-Object ResourceDisplayName, ResourceId, PrincipalDisplayName, PrincipalType
    $report = $appRoles | Select-Object ResourceDisplayName, ResourceId, PrincipalDisplayName, PrincipalType
    $owners | ForEach-Object {
        $owner = $_
        $report | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "OwnerDisplayName" -Value $owner.DisplayName
        $report | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "OwnerUserPrincipalName" -Value $owner.UserPrincipalName
    }
    $report | Export-Csv -Path "C:\\Users\\Documents\\folder1\\important-$date.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force
}
```

**file:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you but it produces the same results.  The file does not capture the Owners assigned to the application if there are any or not. Located here: Home > (tenanname.com) | Enterprise applications > Enterprise applications | All applications > (application name) Under the Manage menu > Owners

Comment: @bacjac38 In my environment, the enterprise application owner for the secret app is **`SriGmail`**https://i.imgur.com/mIs1eLC.png also I can able to fetch in my Excel https://i.imgur.com/V0mxjMj.png

Comment: Your example works when you only have a single owner but if you have multiple owners, it generates an error and attempts to overwrite the first entry: "Add-Member : Cannot add a member with the name "OwnerUserPrincipalName" because a member with that name already exists." 

Just like multiple PrincipleDisplayName, I need the report to show multiple the OwnerDisplayName and OwnerUserPrincipleNames

Comment: I know I'm mixing single properties with arrays of properties. I can't seem to find how to extract the owners (single and multiple) into the report. Any guidance would be appreciated.